# Button Visibility According To Listbox ListboxItem Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, show-hide

I have a situation as follows
[image]

I want to hide delete button when no item is selected & show when something is selected.

Also hide that button if user selects an item & clicks elsewhere (which represents that user is no longer working with the listbox).

I tried `LostFocus` events, checking `SelectedIndex` etc. but no success. Any idea how to do this?

```
    private void ListBoxItem_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (button.IsFocused != true) // checking if user has selected an item & clicking on button (valid action)
        {
            listbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }

    private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us your current work :)

Comment: It's a very, very bad idea from the point of usability. Imagine the person, who looks at your application at first time or very rarely. He/she must know/remember, that until item isn't selected *and* list box is focused, the full list of available actions isn't clear. It's not obvious, and it is better to display button always, but disable it, when related action isn't possible.

Comment: @Dennis: yes, I agree. But in my case simplicity is important according to the design of UI. User should not see the stuff all around enabled/disabled, but it should be available when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph's answer is correct but you don't need a converter.

You can achieve the same result with a simple trigger:

```
<ListBox>
    ...
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="YOUR_BUTTON'S_NAME" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Edit: It's indeed impossible to use TargetName in a Style Setter.

So, the closest solution I could make work is to create a DataTrigger:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <TextBlock Text="Button"/>
    </Button>
    <ListBox x:Name="MyList">
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Something"/>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Error - `The name "button1" is not recognized.`

Comment: @MangeshGhotage it should work if the button's x:Name is button1

Comment: Weird. Join this chat and paste your xaml please: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67482/wpf-quest-mangeshghotage

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to the "not recognized" problem? I am trying to do basically this exact thing (well, enable/disable button based on `SelectedIndex` property), and while I thought I'd be able to refer to the button from the list box style or the list box from the button style, I cannot figure out to do either. Unfortunately, the chat you created was deleted, and this answer hasn't been updated to reflect any resolution. :(

Comment: @PeterDuniho My answer was indeed incorrect because you cannot use a Setter's TargetName in a Style. A workaround would be a DataTrigger (I edited my answer with a working solution) with either the ElementName of the binding set or a RelativeSource.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, I did manage to figure out the `DataTrigger` option on my own, but thank you very much for adding that example to your answer. (Insert here my standard rant about WPF offering half a dozen ways to do any given thing, where each way has slightly different and incompatible mechanisms :) )

Answer (score 0):

For the first half of the question the best way is to use a converter like so :
1. add a Converter class :

```
 public class VisibilityConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value == null ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

2.add it to the Window resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

3. and use it to hide/show your button :

```
<Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="listBox">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Fist"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Second"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Third"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Fourth"/>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="delete" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=listBox,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
```

And for the second half of the question, you must handle the `MouseDown` event in your window:

```
MouseDown="MainWindow_OnMouseDown"
```

and add the following handler (that will reset the `SelectedItem` of the list to `null`)

```
 private void MainWindow_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

Comment: 1) Converter is overkill here, there will be enough a simple data trigger. 2) Handling mouse events this way will hide a button too, when user will try to click it (although, I'm not sure and can't check right now). Actually, the question, as it stands, is not a way to go.

Comment: Right. So feel free to post the belonging MVVM solution.

Comment: No when the button or the list received the Click it won't be intercepted by the Window, and yes i kinda agree with you that using a Converter is some over work, but i believe that it is one way to go.

Comment: @deafjeff what Mvvm solution !!

Comment: @Joseph using IPropertyChanged, not changing button visibility in code.

Comment: the dude didn't asked for that, he didn't even tag mvvm in his question that's why i codebehind it, besides there are no need for INotifyPropertyChanged here !

Comment: OK. But please note that if you don't use that approach, you have unwanted behavior, like here you reset always the listbox when clicking elsewhere. The author only wants the button to hide, not the listbox selection to be reset. If you could edit that it should be a good solution (no matter if a visibility converter is used or not.)

Comment: SelectedItem Is Set => Button Visible , 
!(Button Visible) => !(SelectedItem Is Set)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition -_-

Answer (score 0):

Run this code separately and try.it is working for me here.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lst">
            <ListBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard> 
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ListBox.Triggers>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBoxItem1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBoxItem2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBoxItem3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBoxItem4</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"  Content="Delete" Height="30" Width="100">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource alredayDefinedStyleKey}"  TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>                           
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=lst}" Value="{x:Null}" >
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="1">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This seems to be simple & working.. just a little help.. when I click the button, it triggers click event & disappears. Can I prevent its hiding when its clicked? else it is working like a charm!

Comment: Set property Focusable="False" to button

Comment: I want to apply this for multiple buttons. I mean, I have 3 option buttons & I need to do same thing for all of them. Also they have some other style already applied. Will you please provide solution for this case?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5jq13c. please be specific for your requirement..........do you want to show all 3 button visible on listbox single item selection ?

Answer (score -1):

`LostFocus` will only fire, if the element loses Logical focus. Use `LostKeyboardFocus` event. Then you're one step closer.